# Converting UIImage into NSData

Tags: ios, internet-explorer, uiimage, nsdata

I need to upload a image from iOS device to web service. While uploading image i used;

```
    NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage);
```

Actually it works fine. However the images i uploaded does not show up in IE. 
I tried uploading both JPG and PNG i can see the images in all other browsers but it does not work in IE. So i thought that it can be about converting it to NSData.

Is there any other way to convert UIImage to NSData?

Or any other idea that might be causing the problem?

Here is the way i upload the image;

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage);

if (pictureData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.JPG\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:pictureData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: the problem most likely isn't on how you upload your image but on how it is displayed on your website.

Comment: I am uploading it to JIRA with using its own REST services. This functionality is being used by lots of different applications. So there must be something wrong with my code. This is what i am using: [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp2011456)

Comment: Besides setting the *correct* content-type header, you should set the size of the content of the *multipart* (size of the image data) explicitly.  NSURLConnection will do that for the whole message, but I strongly believe not for the *multipart*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your image to a PNG representation and then you rename it image.JPG

IE might get confused by that.
Try to either rename your image to image.PNG or use UIImageJPEGRepresentation

Comment: I tried every combination of them like using JPG with UIImageJPEGRepresentation, using PNG with UIImagePNGRepresentation naming them as image.PNG, naming them as image.JPG... but none of them worked..

Comment: Did you also change the content type ? Another solution could be to send your image in a base64 encoding. Have a look at QSUtilities to convert data to base64 https://github.com/mikeho/QSUtilities

Comment: Well, Nicolas meant, the Content-Type of the multipart must match the actual type of the image. In your code it does not.